# Select the maximum value from a table with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables; users, tests, and results.

I made a query which will take all the answers from the tests done by the users.

When the users does the test multiple times it, the correct answer is saved in a new row.

For example, when a user does 1 test five times, the correct answers are saved in table but they are treated like 5 individual test.

So, if I have a number of test of 150, if a user does only 100 different tests, and 1 test 10 times, in the progress bar it will show 110 tests done so far out of the 150 test available, instead of 101 out of 150.

This is the SQL I used for this:

```
SELECT id_test
     , titlu
     , capitol
     , materii_bac.materie
     , teste_bac.intrebari
     , corecte
     , utilizatori.id
     , COUNT(*) AS rez
  FROM 
     (
      (
       ( rezultate_bac 
    JOIN teste_bac 
      ON rezultate_bac.id_test = teste_bac.id
       )
    JOIN materii_bac
      ON teste_bac.materie = materii_bac.id
      )  
   JOIN utilizatori  
     ON rezultate_bac.id_utilizator = utilizatori.id
     ) 
 WHERE utilizatori.id = '$user' 
 GROUP 
    BY id_test 
 ORDER 
    BY rez DESC
```

Thank you !

Comment: You dont need to Bracket your JOINS

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I solved. The query is good actually, I take the minimum values which is 1 from values of sql, and then I sum the values.